# Unable to use declared variable in DDL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

Please consider below simple code

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    _VARCHAR_SIZE int := 200;
BEGIN
    create table mytable(
        id int primary key,
        name varchar( _VARCHAR_SIZE )
    );
END $$;
```

On executing above code I am getting error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "_VARCHAR_SIZE"
LINE 14:   name character varying(_VARCHAR_SIZE) NOT NULL,
                                  ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 222
```

Why postgres is not recognizing declared variable in DDL

I don't want to use `EXECUTE` to make whole statement dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally Postgres knows two type of commands - commands (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, ..) and queries (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`). Every command has some special implementation. Queries are implemented together with steps: parsing, analyzing, optimization, execution. There is high probability so queries will be executed repeatedly. Commands usually are not executed more times. Then queries has special optimization for repeated execution - parametrized plan. The plan is sequence of steps of query execution. Usually it is same, but the parameters (variables) are different - You can search Pavel or Tomas, you can insert Pavel or Tomas. There is nothing similar for commands.

You can use plpgsql variables everywhere where is possible to use plan parameters. PlpgSQL runtime join it. And you cannot to use variables else where. DDL statements (commands has not plans), and then you cannot to use variables there. Only one alternative is *dynamic sql* - `EXECUTE` command in PLpgSQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you use psql, please try:

```
\set a 1

CREATE TABLE a (a varchar(:a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass this as a query parameter. For this, you do need dynamic SQL:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    _VARCHAR_SIZE int := 200;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
        'create table mytable(id int primary key, name varchar( %s ));',
        _VARCHAR_SIZE
    );
END $$;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22993da779d40e555036c6dceab27fbf)**

Comment: In question I already mentioned that I don't want to use `EXECUTE`. This will make my complete statement dynamic string. I just want to pass size as variable.

Comment: @afzalex: I am afraid that this is not possible. But if you don't like my answer I can remove it. Maybe someone else will come up with another solution...

Comment: Do you know what is the reason for this?

Comment: i think that is a dinamic query like say in the documentation, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN and always you must use EXECUTE clause

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo Using EXECUTE has it's own drawbacks. Mind you that I could have used that variable to insert data. According to you I should use EXECUTE for that also. The point is variable doesn't work only in DDL (acc. to my understanding here) and my question is why is it so.

Comment: @afzalex DDL commands has not based on execution of execution plan. Without execution plan, there is not a possibility how to parametrize these commands. SELECT and DML are based on execution plans - and these plans can holds variables. DDL has not any similar - should not to have - because there is absolutely different semantic, and then only one way how to do "parametrization" is using dynamic SQL `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @PavelStehule Please post your comment as answer. I beleive it is a proper explaination for question. Is there any official documentation anywhere that explain this?

Comment: @afzalex there is no way you can do this without dynamic SQL

Comment: @afzalex - I wrote answer. I am not sure if it is somewhere in Postgres documentation - maybe not - I am one of developers who are working on development of plpgsql runtime (language). It's implementation detail maybe not too important for mayor part of developers. But maybe it is in plpgsql documentation - long time ago I read it.